# Calculus of Variation, Need help finding Euler Lagrange Equation for Klein Gordon

Tags: matrices, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I have been given the following Question:
Find the Euler-Lagrange equation for the variational problem with the fundamental Integral:
$$
\int_G\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(A_{\alpha \beta}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t_{\alpha}}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t_{\beta}}\right)+\frac{1}{2}m^2u^2\right]dt_1...dt_4
$$
where $m$ is a constant and
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}-1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\\
\alpha,\beta=1,2,3,4
$$
I am not sure where to start here. Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write
$$
I(u) = \frac{1}{2}\int_G \langle A\nabla u,\nabla u\rangle + m^2u^2.
$$
If $u$ is a critical point of $I$, then
$$
0=\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\bigg|_{\epsilon =0}I(u+\epsilon v)
$$
for all functions $v$ of compact support. (This condition says that the first derivative of $I$ vanishes at $u$.) The right hand side of this equation can be computed via integration by parts and the symmetry of $A$:
\begin{align}
0
&=\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\bigg|_{\epsilon =0}I(u+\epsilon v)
\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_G \langle A\nabla v,\nabla u\rangle +\langle A\nabla u,\nabla v\rangle +2m^2uv
\\
&=\int_G (-\mathrm{div}(A\nabla u)+m^2 u)v.
\end{align}
Hence $0=\int_G (\mathrm{div}(A\nabla u)+m^2 u)v$ **for all compactly supported $v$**. This can only be true if the integrand is zero, i.e. if
$$
0=-\mathrm{div}(A\nabla u)+m^2 u = - A_{\alpha\beta}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t_{\alpha} \partial t_{\beta}} +m^2u.
$$
This is the Euler-Lagrange equation, which is just the Klein-Gordon equation.